# Scrapy Crawl E-Commerce Site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy to crawl a couple of images from Carousell. An example of the query and site page is https://sg.carousell.com/search/products/?query=shirt To load more images however requires clicking on the "Load more" button. I noticed this triggers a query to the API at /api-service/search/search/3.3/products/ This API does not seem to support > 20 results and from observing the network traffic to the API requires the Session value which is hashed to be somehow incremented which I can't figure out how. Could anyone assist in suggesting how to increment the Session Id to get the next set of results or alternative methods to extract the listings from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the session & searchContext back in the page itself:

```
import json

initial_state = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"initialState")]/text()').extract_first()
first = initial_state.index("window.initialState=") + len("window.initialState=")
data = json.loads(initial_state[first:])
session_id = data['SearchListing']['parameters']['session']
search_context = data['SearchListing']['parameters']['searchContext']
```

With this you should be able to construct the api-call.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the session needs to be somehow incremented to get the next set of results. Otherwise the same results get returned if you use the original session id.